# excel formula for randomizing sales based on percentage

Tags: excel

I am creating a cash flow model.  I have 28 properties which I want to calculate their monthly costs for.
I would like to sell 10% of the properties in year one (during a random month), 15% in year 2, 25% year 3, 30% year 4, 12% year 5, 8% year 6.

All entries per month have a base cost (maintanance fees), and if the property is sold will generate a profit minus a sales tax.

Is there any formula i can use to automate this?  Im doing monthly cashflows for 84 months so it would take a while to input by hand.
Thanks

Comment: If you can do one property, you can just fill down or copy and paste the formulas for the other properties.  As for the "random" part, it's not clear what you really want there (and how can you sell 10% of 26 properties?)

Comment: This doesn't sounds like a one-formula job. If you are building a model in Excel, it's a good idea to separate the data from the analysis. You've asked about the analysis but haven't said anything about the available data. Probably your desire for automation can be achieved, but we will need to know more about what's going on under the hood. Make sense?

Comment: do you mean percentage of value? as @TimWilliams points out, how do you sell part of a property

Comment: No, I mean I'd round to the nearest whole number.
say I wanted to sell 2.6 properties during the 3rd calendar year, i'd want it to "sell"/insert a custom value into a cell in 3 different cells over the 12-cell period.

Comment: why not make decisions on which % a property falls within. Apparently 3 the first year, and whatever each following year (since) the rounding messes it all up. assign a prefix to each for that year group and run subtotals for those yearly groups.

Answer (score 0):

If always rounding to the nearest whole number one property would remain after six years, so rounding 8.4 up to 9 to avoid that and adding some property values net of sales taxes for an example, a formula such as:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(ROW()-1,J$5:J$13,0),J$4*COUNTIF(J$5:J$13,$A2),""),"")
```

in B2 copied across and down to G13 may save some labour, assuming J5:O5 has been filled with `=RANDBETWEEN(1,12)` and that formula has been copied down to the number of cells shown in J3:O3:

[image: SO11460484 example]